# How to format date in ant table?

Tags: javascript, datatable, antd

I have a table with 6 columns, one of these columns is a date, The default display format of the date is `2020-04-30T21:30:07.000Z` I want to change it to `30-04-2020`.

```
export const columns = [
    { title: `ID`, dataIndex: `invoice_id`},
    { title: `Invoice Number`, dataIndex: `invoice_number` },
    { title: `Amount`, dataIndex: `invoice_amount`},
    { title: `Store Name`, dataIndex: `store_name`},
    { title: `Supplier Name`, dataIndex: `supplier_name`},
    { title: `Creation Date`, dataIndex: `invoice_date`,},
  ]

<Table bordered columns={columns} dataSource={invoices_list} />
```

I believe there should be a way to pass date format to the columns. I looked into the `ant` table documentations but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the antd documentation (https://ant.design/components/table/#API) it doesn't seems to have a property to handle your case. You should duplicate your column `invoices_date` to `invoices_date_printabble` which will have the good format to be printed.

```js
invoices_list.map(el => {
    let date = new Date(el.invoices_date)
    el.invoices_date_printabble = date.getDay()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getFullYear()
})
```

And now your list is printable.

```
export const columns = [
    { title: `ID`, dataIndex: `invoice_id`},
    { title: `Invoice Number`, dataIndex: `invoice_number` },
    { title: `Amount`, dataIndex: `invoice_amount`},
    { title: `Store Name`, dataIndex: `store_name`},
    { title: `Supplier Name`, dataIndex: `supplier_name`},
    { title: `Creation Date`, dataIndex: `invoices_date_printabble`},
  ]

<Table bordered columns={columns} dataSource={invoices_list} />
```

Comment: I was thinking to handle it this way but from performance wise it might affect the performance if the list is long. in my case it could be up to 1000 objects in the list

Comment: Please add ')' to close map function

Comment: I don't think that a processing on a list of 1000 object will never cause lags on your frontend, if so you should consider using workers (developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/…). Have fun :)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to implement it is to define a 'render' for a date column like

```
{
 title: 'Published at',
 dataIndex: 'publishedAt',
 key: 'publishedAt',
 width: 210,
 render: ((date:string) => getFullDate(date)) }
```

and just utilize date formatting function getFullDate. In your case it can look like

```
export const getFullDate = (date: string): string => {
  const dateAndTime = date.split('T');

  return dateAndTime[0].split('-').reverse().join('-');
};
```

In this case you'll also avoid using external libraries and will have a function to format the date in other places.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it using `moment.js` library.

First install moment.js into your project

```
npm i moment
```

Second import it to your component

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Third change date format:

```
let invoices=response.data
invoices.map(el => {
    let date = moment(new Date(el.invoice_date));
    el.invoice_date = date.format("DD/MM/YYYY")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me!

```
export const columns = [
      {
      title: "ID",
      key: "key",
      render: (record) => {
        return (
          <div> 
            <p>{moment(record.invoice_id).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}</p>
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use moment.js in the render method of the column options:

Your moment format of your existing date can be found in the moment documentation.

For future reference you can always use a millisecond timestamp and convert to whatever date format you want with moment.

```
export const columns = [
....
{ title: "Creation Date", 
dataIndex: "invoices_date",
render: (invoice_date) => { return (<p>{moment(invoices_date, **"Moment Format"**).format(DD-MM-YYYY)}</p>)},
```

]